# Feasibility of using a laser as a heat sink

Tags: thermodynamics, laser

In the science-fiction author Stephen Baxter's Xeelee novels, there are some references to a "refrigeration laser" on Earth. For example, from Xeelee Vengeance:

> ...and the splayed purple glow of a refrigeration laser, dumping waste
>   heat into the sky as it had since the construction in the Recovery era
>   centuries before.

Basically, it's a large scale laser that counteracts global warming by "beaming" heat into space.

Is this concept reasonable in any way? Could a laser act as a heatsink by "beaming" away heat?

Comment: Well [laser cooling is real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_cooling), is this what you’re looking for?

Comment: FWIW, all lasers (using current technology) produce significant amounts of waste heat. Typical laser diodes have an efficiency around 50%, but apparently there are laser diodes that are 85% efficient.

Comment: @KyleKanos No. I saw it when googling the subject. But in the book the laser is used to shed heat from its point of origin, rather than cooling something at the laser's impact point.

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm not very well versed in physics, but it seems intuitive to me that a laser would generate heat at it's operating point, making the concept rather dubious. But I wanted to ask the question here in case I'm missing something.

Comment: If you can harvest energy from the atmosphere and use it the feed your laser, even if some of the heat is dissipated in the process, you will still succeed to send some energy into the space. Now the "hard" part is more into the harvesting of the energy from the atmosphere